# http submission changes custom body in angular

Tags: angular, http

Please assist with the following:

I need to submit the following object to the API:

```
{
    "Packages":[
        {
            "PackageEntityID": 1234
        }        
    ]
}
```

I have to build my own custom object:

```
const data = {
      Packages:
      [
          {
              PackageEntityID: id
          }
      ]
    };
```

but this makes my object look like this when submitting to the API, which in turn returns a error because the object is not formatted correctly:

```
{
    Packages:[
        {
            PackageEntityID: "1234"
        }        
    ]
}
```

I need the titles to be in strings and I need the ID to be a integer and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably passing `id` as string. Make sure `id` is number or convert it to number.

```js
const data = {
      Packages:
      [
          {
              PackageEntityID: parseInt(id)
          }
      ]
    };
```

If your API is accepting JSON everything should be ok. `PackageEntityID` is not a title. It is called a key and other side of `:` is the value. If you really do need the quotes for keys then `JSON.stringify()`  takes a JavaScript object and transforms it into a JSON string.

```js
JSON.stringify(data)
// {"Packages":[{"PackageEntityID":1234}]}
```

Comment: Id is set to number: ```public purchasePackage(id: number)```